# Problem in Overlaying KML files on google Map displayed in Browser

Tags: file, kml

We are in the process of overlaying some KML files on Google Map displayed in Browser. The KML files when displayed on the normal Google Maps works as expected. But, when displayed in the google Map displayed in the browser the KML files are not getting displayed as expected. The KML files are generated by converting the Shape files using an online converter tool.

We used the original shape files and retrieved county information from US Census Bureau Site.

Need Help in resolving the issue.

Comment: Do you mean in Google Earth it works as expected? What is "normal Google Maps" referring to?

Comment: Now that the KML file gets rendered correctly on Google Map. Could some one assist in Overlaying Mulitple KML files on a single Google Map

Comment: You just have to create multiple layers and set their map property to your map instance. You'll most likely have separate URLs for each of your KML files, so you'll just vary the constructor with those. See my answer below for the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you've provided the code that you're using, or the .kml file, so I can see where it goes wrong.

Anyway, you can add a kml to your map like this:

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function initialize() {
          new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/geo/?g=322338@N20&lang=en-us&format=feed-georss').setMap(
            new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP})
          );
        }
    </script> 
</head> 

<body onload="initialize()"> 
  <div id="map_canvas" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;top:0"></div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating your KmlLayer?

The URL passed into the constructor of the KmlLayer must be a publicly accessible one so that Google's server can retrieve the KML/KMZ then render it on the tile which it returns to you.

```
var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://this/must/not/be/localhost/file.kmz');
```

As seen in Google Maps v3 API Reference:

> A KmlLayer adds geographic markup to the map from a KML, KMZ or GeoRSS file that is hosted on a publicly accessible web server.

Keep in mind there are also limits imposed on the KML and KMZ files. Information on this can be found here: http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/mapsSupport.html